# How to implement a nested for loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to loop through the following array of objects and get the value for each objects:

```
[
  {"12/20/20": "12/21/20", __rowNum__: 1},
  {"12/20/20": "12/22/20", __rowNum__: 2},
  {"12/20/20": "12/23/20", __rowNum__: 3},
  {"12/20/20": "12/24/20", __rowNum__: 4},
  {"12/20/20": "12/25/20", __rowNum__: 5}
]
```

**Attempted the following**

```
 let fdata= []
      this.fileData.forEach(element => {
        for(let i in element){
          fdata.push(i)
        }
      });
```

**Result Getting**
I am getting the same item repeated using my function above

```
["12/20/20", "12/20/20", "12/20/20", "12/20/20", "12/20/20"]
```

Note: I copy pasted output from console, so that I don't make any mistake formatting properly

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Is it an Array or an Object?  If it's an Object, just use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) otherwise use `.map()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with one line by using `.map` and `Object.values`

```js
var data=[{"12/20/20": "12/21/20"},
 {"12/20/20": "12/22/20"},
 {"12/20/20": "12/23/20"},
 {"12/20/20": "12/24/20"},
 {"12/20/20": "12/25/20"}]
 
 console.log(data.map(item=>Object.values(item)[0]))
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want this

```
let fdata= []
  this.fileData.forEach(element => {
    for(let i in element){
      fdata.push(element[i])
    }
  });
```

You are pushing key, not the value.

```
key       value
12/20/20: "12/25/20"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function iterate(array){
 return array.map(x => Object.values(x)[0])
}
```

```js
function iterate(array){
 return array.map(x => Object.values(x)[0]) 
}

console.log(iterate([
  {"12/20/20": "12/21/20"},
  {"12/20/20": "12/22/20"},
  {"12/20/20": "12/23/20"},
  {"12/20/20": "12/24/20"},
  {"12/20/20": "12/25/20"}
]))
```